# Trying to show all gallery images on a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am trying to develop an Android app that shows all Gallery images on a ViewFlipper.
Before posting this I made some searches but I didn't find what I look for, all examples was showing static images like this :

```
<ViewFlipper 
        android:id="@+id/flipper1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:flipInterval="3000"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_in_right"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_out_left"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >


        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/img1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/str_img1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/img2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/str_img2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/img3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/str_img3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/img4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/str_img4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/img5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/str_img5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </ViewFlipper>
```

What I want to do is just select one image from gallery and then slide Right/Left to see the gallery content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855399/how-to-implement-image-gallery-in-gridview-in-android

Comment: This is what I was looking for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.html