# How to collect the images in mobile using android

Tags: android, photos

Have doubt in collecting the images from both SDcard and Phone storage, using android i need to get all the images and have to store that in a listview, please suggest some idea or related post.

Have searched in google but dint get solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean all of the images displayed on you device's gallery?

Comment: Yes, Even need to collect the images saved from whatsapp  and facebook.

Comment: [Loading all the images from gallery into the Application in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590514/loading-all-the-images-from-gallery-into-the-application-in-android)

Comment: see my answer down here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is important:(taken from the link below)

"You are using MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI which is only the external storage.For the internal there is MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI."

[Loading all the images from gallery into the Application in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590514/loading-all-the-images-from-gallery-into-the-application-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, The links helps to get some idea.

Comment: come back if you need more help :)

Answer (score 0):

Download [Mobogenie](http://www.mobogenie.com/) Software.Then install it.Finally connect it with the Phone.Then you can move all your images stored in SDcard to mobile devices.