# How to auto load all images from phone gallery to image slider in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, loops

I want to build a image slider that can shift images automatically with looping all images from phone's gallery. My android device is android 4.0.4. Can anyone help me out?

I have successfully built a image slider that can shift images automatically, but all the images are from the `drawable` resource that I created using Android Studio. I want the images come from gallery for better user interface.

My code is like this:

```
int images[] = {R.drawable.slide1, R.drawable.slide7, R.drawable.slide10};
```

It requires looping with array to do this, but I am a beginner of java.

Answer (score 0):

1) content provider may help. like

```
private ArrayList<String> getImages(Context context) {
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
        ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<String>();
        String absolutePathOfImage = null;
        uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME };

        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

            listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
        }
        return listOfAllImages;
    }
```

[loading images from gallery with content provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590514/loading-all-the-images-from-gallery-into-the-application-in-android)

also look to the file ways as those are also useful.

[listing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646984/how-to-list-files-in-an-android-directory)

[loading images from file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path)