# How to import image from gallery in android studio

Tags: java, android

In this code, there are two images in `stickerList`, which come from drawable resources and can be set into my `ImageView` perfectly. Now I want to pick images from the gallery (rather than specific hardcoded drawables) and set any image I want. A new image from gallery which will override the previous or main one. How can i do that?

```java
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    public class StickerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StickerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        int[] stickerList = new int[]{R.drawable.aa, R.drawable.bb};

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_sticker, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.imgSticker.setImageResource(stickerList[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return stickerList.length;
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView imgSticker;

            ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imgSticker = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgSticker);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mStickerListener != null) {
                            mStickerListener.onStickerClick(
                                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                            stickerList[getLayoutPosition()]));
                        }
                        dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android pick images from gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery)

Comment: Not from specific location or sd card, although It seems good, but how can I implement this in my code?

Comment: In stickerList I want to show all images from gallery, then user can choose any images he want to add. @VolkanSahin45

Comment: Take a look! https://stackoverflow.com/q/18590514/8114201