# MEDIASTORE images, got nothing

Tags: android, mediastore

I added the request premissions for reading files tried this method inside my activity but nothing shows,like there is no images in real devices and emulator,what am i doing wrong?

```
    fun storaheread() {      
    val imageProjection = arrayOf(
      MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
      MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
      MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
      MediaStore.Images.Media._ID
    )
    val imageSortOrder = "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN} DESC"
    val cursor = contentResolver.query(
      MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
      imageProjection,
      null,
      null,
      imageSortOrder
    )
    cursor.use {
      it?.let {
        val idColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        val nameColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
        val sizeColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE)
        val dateColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN)
        while (it.moveToNext()) {
          val id = it.getLong(idColumn)
          val name = it.getString(nameColumn)
          val size = it.getString(sizeColumn)
          val date = it.getString(dateColumn)
          val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            id
          )
          // add the URI to the list
          // generate the thumbnail
//          val thumbnail = (this as Context).contentResolver.loadThumbnail(contentUri, Size(480, 480), null)
        Log.d("image name",name)
        }
      } ?: kotlin.run {
        Log.e("TAG", "Cursor is null!")
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `getColumnIndexOrThrow` Does it throw?

Comment: no,not throwing anything

Answer (score 0):

you can check out this similar question, it may help you achieve this situation.

[Loading all the images from gallery into the Application in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590514/loading-all-the-images-from-gallery-into-the-application-in-android)