# Get all the images from the Gallery in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to make my own Gallery in Android but I can´t find the way to bring all the photos without selecting them. I have tried this:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

But opens an intent in which I have to select one or more photos. **Is there a way I can bring them all without selecting them?**

Answer (score -1):

This is a sample code for it

```
public class GetImageActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                    }
                });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

For your question hell of solutions is available in SOF. So before posting a new question google it first.look into these examples if you face any problem..

[android gallery into grid style menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782922/android-gallery-into-grid-style-menu)

[GridView loading photos from SD Card](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/gridview-loading-photos-from-sd-card.html)

[How to implement Image Gallery in Gridview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855399/how-to-implement-image-gallery-in-gridview-in-android)

[Android-Fetch images from sdcard and display in gridview](http://anusreeanair.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-fetch-images-from-sdcard-and.html)

Comment: This is an intent to select images from gallery

Comment: @CecilPaul Yes i know, before the question was about getting the images from gallery. later it got edited by the question seeker.